# Woocommerce pre_get_posts causing problems

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue at hand. I am using `add_action('pre_get_posts','test_hook')` inside my theme's functions.php and call it inside the products page: `do_action('pre_get_posts');`

The thing is that when I call that action, other functions hooked into pre_get_posts are called and I get the following error: `Call to a member function is_main_query() on a non-object in wc-deprecated-functions.php`

I looked up that code and it looks like:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wc_shop_order_status_backwards_compatibility' );
function wc_shop_order_status_backwards_compatibility( $q ) {
   if ( $q->is_main_query() ) {
      return;
   }
//...and it goes on
}
```

I need to hook my function without affecting this ones, but I don't really see how. If I comment this function, another one hooked into pre_get_posts returns the same error.

**PS:** My function is empty. The way I see it, even without creating my own hook and only by calling the hook within that page (archive_products.php) creates this error.

Comment: You shouldn't call `do_action('pre_get_posts')` on your page...it gets called automatically after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

Comment: WOW...thank you!! Could you please write that as an an answer?

Comment: @rnevius By the way: I have read countless forums and documentations and it didn't say you needn't call it. But judging from other hooks people have posted, where they called do_action, I thought it was mandatory. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call `do_action('pre_get_posts')` on your page...it gets called automatically after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run. See [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for a quick explanation.

More context: NONE of the core [WordPress Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) need to be explicitly called (and none of them are called with `do_action()`). While something like `wp_head();` is called in the template, this is actually the [wp_head() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), not the [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

WordPress is confusing sometimes, because it duplicates names of actions, hooks, and functions.

Comment: Thank you again! Yes, it is confusing. Working with woocommerce I see a lot of code looking like `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );` and I really thought I should do the same thing. I remain in your debt! :)

Comment: If you register a *custom* action hook (one that isn't a core WordPress action, such as `'woocommerce_before_shop_loop'`), you'll definitely need to explicitly call `do_action()`. These are still usually called in a **functions.php** or plugin settings file though, rather than the template. :-)

Comment: Okay. I keep learning new things every day and I am glad about it.

Comment: By the way, how can I send parameters to my function which is hooked into pre_get_posts? on products_archive.php I read 3 GET variables which I need to use in my function.

Comment: You should be able to use [get_query_var()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) in your function...but you may want to open up a new question on here if that doesn't work.